# Variable error in VBA find command

Tags: excel, vba

My code spontaneously stopped working. I am getting an object variable error when it tries to execute the find command. Whats going on there? Oddly it was working fine yesterday and all of a sudden...

```
    Sub Combiner()
Macro1 Macro

With Application                        ' Scrubs settings that slow process
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

   Dim RangeCells As Range
   Dim CellVal As Range

' Do Loop for renaming Container Numbers

Worksheets("Input").Activate
Range("A1").Select

If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

    ' Copy All
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select
        Selection.Copy

     Worksheets("Backup").Activate
     Range("A1").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Paste

    Worksheets("Input").Activate

    ' Recall UK
    Range("W2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Recall UK"
    Range("W2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' Kill Archive Location
    Columns("AA:AA").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

       Set RangeCells = Range("Z2:Z201")

       For Each CellVal In RangeCells


          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          CellVal.Select

          Sheets("Source").Activate
          Worksheets("Source").Cells.Find(CellVal, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate <-- Gets Stuck Here

          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
          ActiveCell.Copy
          Sheets("Input").Activate
          ActiveSheet.Paste
          Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Next CellVal

    ' Kill title row
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    ' Copy All
        ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select
        Selection.Copy

End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

'
End Sub
```

Comment: That error will occur if the value you are searching for is not found. You should **always** test if the value was found before proceeding (using a range variable and an `Is Nothing` test)

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the Line (where is gets stuck):

```
CellVal.Select
Sheets("Source").Activate
Worksheets("Source").Cells.Find(CellVal, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate <-- Gets Stuck Here
```

To:

```
CellVal.Select
'Setting the CellValue to a variable    
ActualCellValue = CellVal.Value
Sheets("Source").Activate
Worksheets("Source").Cells.Find(CellVal.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
```

I would think that it is not happy with the referencing.

Also, what you really want to get used to staying away from `Select` and `Selection`. Rather set a direct reference to the `Range` or `WorkSheet`use set what you want. You already using it with *RangeCells* and *CellVal* so you can do it with `Sheets` as well.

For setting up direct reference to sheets and using direct reference for inserting "Recall UK" into cells from W2 to the end of Column W, see below:

```
Sub SomeSuggestions()

Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
Dim BackupSheet As Worksheet

Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
Set InputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set BackupSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Backup")

'And to Copy Recall UK form W2 to the end of the Column
InputSheet.Range("W2", Columns("W").End(xlDown)).FormulaR1C1 = "Recall UK"

End Sub
```